# React Native Slider component not working as expected

Tags: react-native

Working example here: https://snack.expo.io/H1TNJPn8Q

The problem is the reported value of the slider while dragging and the actual value of slider are not visually correct. You can see this in the example above

Here is the code for the test component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      currentValue: 0,
      sliderValue: 0
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Slider 
          style={styles.slider}
          minimumValue={0}
          value={ this.state.sliderValue }
          maximumValue={2589127}
          step={0.001}
          onValueChange={e => {
            this.setState(() => {
              return { currentValue: e }
            })
          }}
          onSlidingComplete={e => {
            this.setState(() => {
              return { sliderValue: e }
            })
          }}
        />
        <Text>{this.state.currentValue}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.sliderValue}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

While the slider drags, I update the value of currentValue. On completion, I set the sliderValue to be the reported value from that function. As you can see, the values are identical every time the sliding is complete but whenever the value of the slider is set, the position of the thumb button jumps back. The distance it jumps back seems farther the higher the slider value is, leading me to think that the slider scale may not be linear for some reason.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way I can accurately track the slider value (and reflect it visually) using vanilla components?

Comment: Why do you need the value of the slider to be a state variable? If you remove it it works as you want. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: `Is there a way I can accurately track the slider value (and reflect it visually) using vanilla components?` obviously yes it works uncontrolled but then I can't track the value

Comment: I think you misunderstood what value in the Slider is. It's actually the initial value of the slider, you don't need to update it yourself unless you have a good reason to. Right now if you remove the value prop from your slider it will work as you want it and you will have the accurate value of the slider stored in the currentValue/sliderValue state variables

Comment: I read the documentation, I understand what the value prop is for. As it stands, setting that prop causes a rerender so "initial value" or not is irrelevant. I am altering that value **without** sliding, so removing the value prop is **not an option**. Yes obviously the slider works as intended in this extremely simple example, that is not the point at all because I need to be able to increment the sliders position and the only way to do that as far as I know is to set it manually.

Comment: I'll restate, " Is there a way I can accurately track the slider value (and reflect it visually) using vanilla components?" I need a slider with a controllable value and I don't want to add a third party lib just for one component in one view

Comment: just curious, but why a maxValue sooo high? 2589127???? D: holy mama.

Comment: this slider was for a podcasting app, that would have been the length of the ep in milliseconds so this particular episode was about 40 min long. In retrospect I probably could have went with a less granular value, this is probably an example of overengineering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was simple enough to fix, all I had to do was change the step from `0.001` to `1`.

```
    <Slider 
      style={styles.slider}
      minimumValue={0}
      value={ this.state.sliderValue }
      maximumValue={2589127}
      step={1} // setting this below 1 seems to cause the problem
      onValueChange={e => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return { currentValue: e }
        })
      }}
      onSlidingComplete={e => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return { sliderValue: e }
        })
      }}
    />
```